# how do I fix ngrok invalid HTTP response error

Tags: ngrok

I am using zphisher. when i create a link to ngrok, the link is generated, but on opening it it says `ngrok gateway error The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response.` I got to know from ngrok error documentation that it is error 3004. they tell the error code and message but no possible way to fix the error. can someone help me please. I think my brother watches YouTube during his online classes and I want to conform it. No phishing. Please. I got absolutely no help from anywhere. Just one of my friend told me that i need an ngrok account for that. tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 26):

After some time I got it fixed doing 2 things:

1. Make sure my local site is http (not https)
2. Running command `ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:PORT`

Comment: As others have stated, you can host a local https site by using the full address instead of just the port: `ngrok http https://localhost:8433`

Answer (score 20):

If your site using https://localhost:port
below really works for me

```
ngrok http https://localhost:port --host-header=rewrite
```

Comment: Tried all kind of syntaxes, but appending `--host-header=rewrite` was the solution.

Comment: Excelent, TCP tunnel is funtional

Comment: --host-header=rewrite is the missing argument, thanks @Mary

Answer (score 14):

For me, this command worked when I was receiving the 3004 error message and trying to access **HTTPS** on `https://localhost:3000`:

```
./ngrok http https://localhost:3000
```

Comment: similarly, mind needed `ngrok http https://localhost:5001 -host-header="localhost:5001"` (as opposed to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-event-grid-trigger-local) which suggests only `ngrok http -host-header=localhost 5001` was needed)

Comment: you can use `-host-header rewrite` for this as well.

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer in [this link](https://camerondwyer.com/2019/09/23/using-ngrok-to-get-a-public-https-address-for-a-local-server-already-serving-https-for-free/) and it solved my problem.

According to this you can use this command instead:

```
ngrok http https://localhost:[port]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty straightforward. Use the localhost:port where your application is running. For example, my Jenkins app is running on

http://localhost:8080

I will run the command `$ngrok http http://localhost:8080`

Notice the http/https difference

Answer (score 0):

my solution is using this command:

```
ngrok http "http://$(ip route get 1.2.3.4 | awk '{print $7}')"
```

your httpd.conf must listen to port 80 or you must add it in the command.
my OS is arch linux.

Answer (score 0):

error message:
"loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://11111.ngrok-free.app/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

I had the same problem with ngrok, my site was in https but all the inner requests were changed to http so for it to work
I have changed the code in EasyAdmin Bundle , the file in in /vendor/easycorp/easyadmin-bundle/src/router/AdminUrlGenerator.php
in line 267 after "$this->isInitialized = false;"
we have to add the line
$url = str_replace("http","https",$url);

and now it works for me.